# how to view all associated data among models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've spent awhile searching for this but I'm not really sure how to ask what I want to know and I think that's my biggest problem here :p

I have the following data models:

User

```
has_many :student_groups, dependent: :destroy
```

Student_Group

```
belongs_to :user
has_many   :students, dependent: :destroy
```

Student

```
belongs_to :student_group
```

I want to view all students across all a given user's student_groups - how to do this?  At the moment, my students#index route is as follows:

```
student_group_students GET    /student_groups/:student_group_id/students(.:format)          students#index
```

students#index seems like the logical place to put this, but it also calls for a student_group_id - meaning it's only the index of students in a given student_group.  Based on my code, that makes sense but is there a way to override it for the students#index view?  For example, in the students#index action in the students controller, something like:

```
def index
  @students = @student_group.all.students
  ...
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

If you want to retrieve a students for a particular users, then you need to send the user id through url. Need to customize the routes.rb

```
@user_group_ids = User.find(params[:user_id]).student_groups.map(&:id)

@students = Student.where('student_group_id IN (?)', @user_group_ids)
```

else if you are finding for the current user, then

```
@user_group_ids = current_user.student_groups.map(&:id)

@students = Student.where('student_group_id IN (?)', @user_group_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I have came up with a better option for you, you can use has_many :through association :

```
User

has_many :student_groups, dependent: :destroy
has_many :students, through: :student_groups

Student_Group

belongs_to :user
has_many   :students, dependent: :destroy

Student

belongs_to :student_group
```

Now you will be able to get all students that are associated with any given user's student_groups like this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@user.students
```

it will look more cleaner. Thanks

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840937/relationship-advice-association-logic-in-rails) i just posted

Comment: that is the best way to define relationship in these three models.

Comment: sorry, which way - the way you stated, the way it is [now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1d8jC.png) or [this](http://i.imgur.com/QH3cdUj.png) way?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `@user = User.find(params[:id])` than try this one:

```
@students = []
@user.student_groups.each |sg|
  @students << sg.students
end
```

Comment: i have that at the moment - and it works - the problem is that it returns all the students in the given student group.  What i want is all of the students that belong to the user among all of his or her student_groups

Comment: @dax as student belongs to student_group, all students in it belongs to a user.
Is there something missing from your question?